# AssetError Bound Method in unit test

Tags: python, django

Currently, I am creating a test script. but I am getting this error:

```
 <bound method Score.percentage of <Score: Score object>> != 100
```

these are my codes:

models.py

```
class Score(models.Model):


    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    score = models.FloatField(null=True, default=0)

    def percentage(self):

        percentage = (score/50) * 100

        return percentage
```

This is my test script (test.py)

```
self.assertEqual(Score.percentage, 100)
```

I am expecting:

```
Score.percentage = 100
```

but I got

```
 <bound method Score.percentage of <Score: Score object>> != 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percentage is a method so you need to call it

```
self.assertEqual(Score.percentage, 100)
```

should be

```
self.assertEqual(Score.percentage(), 100)
```

Note: it still won't work correctly though since you need to call the method on an *instance* of score, and call the instances score (`self.score`) inside of the method instead of score.

Comment: but its fine... i will just be the one to find a way here